When does a sparse failing subsequence of $(a_n)_n\subset\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ exist when $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^na_j = c$ exists
My question is a bit longer than the actual title, so here is the full question: Let $(a_n)_n\subset\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^na_j = c$$
exist for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, it isn't too difficult to show that there exist a dense subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ of $(a_n)$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k} = c$$
where by a "dense" subsequence we mean that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\#(\{n_k: k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap\{1,2,\dots,N\})}{N} = 1$$
Consequently, by a "sparse" subsequence of indices $(n_k)_k$ we mean such a subsequence of indices that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\#(\{n_k: k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap\{1,2,\dots,N\})}{N} = 0$$
Knowing that such a dense subsequence always exist when the limit of the mean exist, what do we know about the existence of sparse sequences $(a_{n_k})_k$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}\neq c$$
I'm interested in learning about any facts and/or references that discuss this question!

If $(a_n)$ is convergent then the limit is necessarily equal to $c$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=c$ for all subsequences. Otherwise $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}\neq c$ for some subsequence, and by choosing a subsequence you can make $(n_k)$ as “sparse” as you want. – Or am I misunderstanding something?

@MartinR I suppose that in principle you are not misunderstanding anything. I may have worded my original text poorly, but what I was hoping to address is the potentially quite naive question of what properties of the sequence $(a_n)_n$ other than failure to converge along the original sequence would show the existence of some sparse failing sequence. But now that I have said it out loud, I don't think that you can answer this in any way other than addressing the convergence of $(a_n)_n$ head on, and then sparsify the some failing subsequence, like you mentioned.
